Galois representation on elliptic curves mod p
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over number field $K$.
Assume that the Galois representation $\rho_K : G_K \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective.
Then we have the isomorphism $G(K(E[p])/K)\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.
In this case, How can I obtain the subgroup of $G(K(E[p])/K)$ corresponding to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?

What have you tried?

@CJDowd I don’t know how to operate the determinant on E[p].

Hint: try using the Weil pairing, particularly the formula $e_p(ax + by, cx + dy) = e_p(x, y)^{ad - bc}$.
